# Properties of Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

For any two elements x and y in G there exists z in G such that y=xz
Prove it is true for every group or give counter example.

---

So far I have:

$ y=xz $

Multiplying on the left by $x^{-1},$ $ x^{-1}y=x^{-1}xz$, or $x^{-1}y=z$

Im not really sure where to go from here. How do I show that this is true for every group? Am I even going in the right direction?

Comment: Take $z=x^{-1}y$

Comment: I think you mean to write $z = x^{-1}y$

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it. What do I do next?

Comment: You've already done the work, all that's left is to structure it properly as a proof (this also might help you convince yourself you really have shown it's true for every group). Remember, the question has 'given you' $x$ and $y$, so you'll start by writing something like "Let $x,y\in G$. Then you have to introduce a new thing, $z$, defined in terms of things you already have (look at the end of the third line of what you've written), and show that it has the property required of it.

Answer (score 0):

If $y = 1$ ( the identity), then this is indeed true.

Now notice that you have in fact proven a general statement:
Take any $x,y$. Let $z = x^{-1}y$. Then $xz = xx^{-1}y = y$. So in fact this holds for any and all groups. Your proof is correct. We know that $x$ must have an inverse, since $G$ is a group. We know by closure that $x^{-1}y$ is always in the group. So you have constructed a necessary $z$ to satisfy the claim.